# Python - assigning variables

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables

[image]

I have a tree diagram as above:

**my data**: `Vnew =[12,13,14,15,16]` - no coordinate available

```
     `V =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
```

- each point in this list has a predefined coordinate.

**What I need**:
1) Assign coordinates to each point in `Vnew` in the form of a variable; for example:

```
   newpos = {(x0,y0):12,(x1,y1):13,(x2,y2):14,(x3,y3):15,(x4,y4):16}
```

Here every `(xi,yi)` is a variable.

2) I need to define a function as the summation of the Euclidean distance between every point which has an edge. For the given example, my function will be

```
              `f(x,y) = ED(12,13)+ED(13,3)+ED(12,15)+ED(15,10)`
```

where  `x =[x0,x1,x2,x3]` and `y =[y0,y1,y2,y3]` and `ED` is the Euclidean distance.

I've tried assigning variables as

```
Vnew = [12,13,14,15,16]
d = {}
for v in Vnew: 
    for i in range(5):
        d[('x' + str(i),'y' + str(i))]= v
    print (d)
```

But this gives me something incorret.

```
{('x0', 'y0'): 12, ('x1', 'y1'): 12, ('x2', 'y2'): 12, ('x3', 'y3'): 12, ('x4', 'y4'): 12}
{('x0', 'y0'): 13, ('x1', 'y1'): 13, ('x2', 'y2'): 13, ('x3', 'y3'): 13, ('x4', 'y4'): 13}
{('x0', 'y0'): 14, ('x1', 'y1'): 14, ('x2', 'y2'): 14, ('x3', 'y3'): 14, ('x4', 'y4'): 14}
{('x0', 'y0'): 15, ('x1', 'y1'): 15, ('x2', 'y2'): 15, ('x3', 'y3'): 15, ('x4', 'y4'): 15}
{('x0', 'y0'): 16, ('x1', 'y1'): 16, ('x2', 'y2'): 16, ('x3', 'y3'): 16, ('x4', 'y4'): 16}
```

Can someone please help me to do these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
Vnew = [12,13,14,15,16]
d = {}
for i, v in enumerate(Vnew): 
    d[('x' + str(i),'y' + str(i))]= v
    print (d)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! How can I start my second requirement with this now?

Comment: @ccc What specifically do you want `ED()` to return?

Comment: it's the Euclidean distance of each edge.

Answer (score 1):

Just acces them from [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
Vnew = [12,13,14,15,16]
d = {}
vars_access = vars()
for i, v in enumerate(Vnew):):
    k=(vars_access['x{}'.format(i)], vars_access['y{}'.format(i)])
    d[k]= v
print (d)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/LRpc/1)

For what you want it is not posible in python, take a look at this [example](https://repl.it/LV03/1)

```
a, b, c = range(3)

t = (a, b, c)
l = [a, b, c]

print(a)
print(t)
print(l)

a += 1

print(a)
print(t)
print(l)

#RESULTS
0
(0, 1, 2)
[0, 1, 2]
1
(0, 1, 2)
[0, 1, 2]
```

Since integers are inmutable in python, by the time you build the list or the tuple with the variables python will bind them to the current value that the variable is pointing to. So when you modify the variable adding one more what python really is doing is creating another integer or chosing from an existing one (integers can not mutate) and making the variable point to that one, so in the list and the tuple you lose that track.

For conclusion, just use `strings` with the name of the variables and then use them to access the current variable value with `vars`

Comment: That's a lot of v's aren't you just overwriting it?

Comment: @SamRedway, yes it was a bug, i was coding the live example, thanks for pointing it :)

Comment: Thanks Daniel!! What I'm getting from this code is '{(0, 0): 12, (1, 1): 13, (2, 2): 14, (3, 3): 15, (4, 4): 16}'. But I want '(0,0)' as a variable coordinate; '(x1,y1)'.

Comment: @ccc, then just use the strings for store them and for retrieve them use `vars` as a dicctionary with such string as key always, in my code you get the values of the variables since they are int and they are inmutable in python. You will not get what you think in python, you cant have a tuple with variables.